# Creating Column index similar to spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Is there a way in Javascript, that I can come up with a series of strings that go A-Z, and when reaching Z, starts over with AA-ZZ, then on to AAA-AMJ? Cause I am trying to think of anything that wouldn't have me looping over loops over loops to do it. And I am stuck and open for ideas at this point.

Comment: generate it once and then put it in a text file maybe?

Comment: @nathanhayfield Is that a serious suggestion?

Comment: @TomášZato sounds like it would be faster, think of it as a cache

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this once in php; that is, I needed a function that would take a numerical column index as input and spit out the excel column name. There is a clever function in the php documentation that does it by using modulo of powers of 26. It can be easily converted to js:

```
function num2alpha($n) {
    let $r = '',$i , $n;
    for ($i = 1; $n >= 0 && $i < 10; $i++) {
        $r = String.fromCharCode(65 + ($n % Math.pow(26, $i) / Math.pow(26, $i - 1))) + $r;
        $n -= Math.pow(26, $i);
    }
    return $r;
}
```

[Original Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#Hcom94874)

Usage:

```
num2alpha(0); //A
num2alpha(27); //AB
num2alpha(1023); //AMJ
```

so...

```
let columns=[];
for(let i=0; i<=1023; i++) {
   columns.push(num2alpha(i));
}
//["A","B","C",..."AA","AB",..."AMJ"]
```

or more tersely

```
let columns=[...Array(1024).keys()].map(num2alpha)
```